# Yellow highlighted text in Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, stack-overflow

When I went to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53219202/channel-vs-broker-vs-destination-in-websocket#:%7E:text=Broker,the%20STOMP%20broker%20to%20clients.) some of the text was highlighted in yellow. Is there something wrong with this?

[image]

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [Strange highlighting for a few seconds](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398033/4642212).

Comment: @user289905 Perhaps you could post that comment as an answer so that it could be accepted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't answer this question any better than [Martijn Peters did](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398034/11171084) (which [user289905 pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349128/yellow-highlighted-text-in-stackoverflow/349130#comment1168312_349128)) over on Meta SO.

Quoting his amazing answer:

> The highlight is a [Google search feature](https://www.google.com/amp/s/9to5google.com/2020/06/03/google-search-highlight-website-content/amp/), where it’ll show the matching section on the page by adding a specially formatted URL hash fragment ([starting with `:~:text=`](https://github.com/WICG/scroll-to-text-fragment#tldr)). You got to that page by clicking on a  *featured snippet* at the top of a Google search result and are using Chrome. Google [rolled out the feature worldwide this week](https://www.theverge.com/2020/6/4/21280115/google-search-engine-yellow-highlight-featured-snippet-anchor-text) after testing it in limited settings for a while.
>
> This is not a Stack Overflow feature, and the feature is not limited to just Stack Overflow search results. This is Google’s search engine hooking into Google’s browser (and any other browser that supports [Google's proposed scroll-to-text fragment specification](https://chromestatus.com/feature/4733392803332096)).
>
> See [these instructions on how to turn it off](https://perishablepress.com/disable-chrome-scrolltotextfragment/).
>
> Stack Overflow *could* choose to disable the feature, either by adding a [`Document-Policy: force-load-at-top` HTTP header](https://github.com/WICG/scroll-to-text-fragment#opting-out) (which disables **all** fragment scrolling, including linking to answers and comments), or by [disabling featured snippet support entirely](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6229325). Both options look to me to have too broad an effect, and don't think they would be good options.

**TL;DR**: This isn't specific to Stack Overflow (or any site on Stack Exchange's network,) it's your browser. As a result, this isn't a bug.

Comment: I was torn between posting this answer and not (because Maritjn's answer is just *that good* and taking it feels a tad wrong), but then I realized that this may be a common question in the coming few days as this is a recently-added Chrome feature. Having this question as a good duplicate target will be nice for that eventuality.

Answer (score -6):

It looks like you highlighted some text in your browser. Reload the page and it should go away.

Comment: Not the case. See the url.